# Google Maps local search API: How to pass a query?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is it possible to pass a search query to a Local search Google Maps object?

I've found [this](http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/localsearch/reference.html) but could not find a way to pass a query (i.e. "Pizza").

Answer (score 1):

Try localSearch.execute('Pizza')